# What is meant by pinch-off voltage?

Tags: transistors, jfet

When I read about junction field effect transistors I always get confused about pinch-off voltage in junction field effect transistors. Please explain what this is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-effect_transistor#n-channel for example. If you have trouble with understanding an explanation you heard, please include details about what you heard and what you didn't understand in your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with BJTs, you control current from collector to emitter (Ice) by varying the current into (NPN) or out of (PNP) the base (Ib). If you deprive the base of any current, Ice goes to zero. This is cutoff mode. So the BJT is a *current* controlled current source. The FET on the other hand is a *voltage* controlled current source. In the FET you control the current from drain to source (Ids) by varying the voltage at the gate with respect to the source (Vgs). For N-channel FETs, a positive-slewing Vgs yields a *de*creasing electric field in the channel (hence the name *field effect* transistor) and thus an *in*crease in Ids, and conversely if you drive the gate voltage low enough WRT the source voltage, the electric field in the drain-to-source channel extends all the way across the channel to effectively block current through the channel, so Ids goes to zero, and that Vgs is called **the pinchoff voltage**.  Same is true for the P-channel FET except for opposite polarity Vgs.

NOTE: I was purposely vague about what that Vgs level might be (i.e., operating point, really) for good reason, because it can vary widely one FET to another, but they break down into two categories, depletion mode and enhancement mode. With N-channel depletion mode, you must never drive the gate voltage above the source voltage or else you will destroy the device, and vice-versa for P-channel depletion mode. So for N-channel depletion mode, the entire operation [pinchoff, linear region, saturation region] occurs with the gate voltage lower than the source voltage; pinchoff being the most negative, linear less negative, and saturation less negative still, but never positive or else POOF !  And again all the same except opposite polarity for the P-channel depletion mode. Depletion mode is implemented as a P-N junction with no oxide insulator (and thus is really just a reverse-biased diode, in reality, believe it or not) and this describes one of the two most common types of FETs which is the JFET (J for junction). The other type is the MOSFET (MOS = Metal Oxide Semiconductor) which has the oxide layer and many of them run in enhancement mode; some of them run in depletion mode (less common). Enhancement mode is where you must have a positive Vgs for N-Channel device (negative Vgs for P-Channel device) to have Ids > 0. The pinchoff voltage for this device is some Vgs > 0 (N-channel) or Vgs < 0 (P-channel), depending on the particular device. So if you are used to BJTs, normal operation of an enhancement mode FET looks more like a BJT because the input is forward-biased, whereas normal operation for a depletion mode FET looks kinda weird because the input is reverse-biased.

I remember one particular discrete package N-channel JFET with a pinchoff voltage of -1.5V. I remember one particular discrete package N-channel MOSFET with a pinchoff voltage around +1V. Sorry, can't remember their industry part numbers. But look in a FET manufacturer's data book (ON semiconductor, for example) and you should find a range of devices with different pinchoff voltages.

Update:

References:

[Wiki FETs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-effect_transistor)

[Wiki MOSFETs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET)

[Power MOSFET Vgs[pinchoff] = 2.8V](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2012/7/17/2/21/59/195/smn_/manual/bsc014n06ns_rev2.0.pdf)

[JFET Vgs[pinchoff] = -0.7V](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ENA1218-D.PDF)

Answer (score 1):

**Background**: "Pure" silicon (or germanium) is an insulator. This can be "doped" to become P or N material.
If you have P and N material forming a junction, the doping types will cancel each other out leaving the pure insulator. You need to overcome this, with about 0.6V in silicon (0.2V in germanium).

**FETs**: Now, think of the N material as a hot dog, and the P material (gate) as a surrounding bun. With no voltage on the gate, the P-N cancellation will turn part of the "wall" of the hot dog back into pure insulating silicon. This makes the *area available to carry current* thinner, or increases resistance.

Next, add a power supply to top & bottom of the N-material hot dog. Call the bottom "source" at zero volts, top "drain" at plus (whatever) volts. The P-material bun is at *minus* (a little bit) volts. What happens?
Reverse biasing the PN junction makes the insulating section bigger, "choking" off more current.

**Finally**: When the reverse bias is big enough, the non-conducting region grows too big and totally cuts off all current between source and drain. Like pinching (or folding) a garden hose, or a drinking straw.

Comment: I like this explanation from the device geometry approach, and the analogies.

Comment: Oh, and because the voltage on the drain is different to the voltage at the source, the actual shape of the insulating zone is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a a channel JFET. As the name suggests, the channel is n type while the gates are of p type. When Vgs = 0 V, and drain to source is forward biased, a current flow occurs. Here the depletion region width between the channel and the gates are minimum. This value of Id is the saturation current, Idss. Once Vgs is made -ve (Vgs < 0) ie Gate to Source is reverse biased, then the depletion region width increases more into the channel which in turn reduces the flow of current. So as Vgs becomes more -ve, Id also reduces (inverse proportionality between Vgs and Id). As the reverse bias voltage (Vgs) increases, at a particular value of Vgs, the depletion with pinches off the channel ( depletion region spreads over the channel entirely ) so that no current can flow through it. This particular voltage where Id = 0 is called Pinch off voltage.

For p channel JFET, channel is of p type. So the exact opposite of n channel JFET will be applicable.